# Allow python objects to interact with mathematical operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, custom-operator

I ask it because I remember numpy does it with arrays. I should add two objects that contain monomials.

Alternatively is it possible to create custom mathematical operators? (like the @ of numpy's dot product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very possible. Classes can contain "magic methods" that can allow objects to interact with `+` and other operators. Specifically, [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) section of the documentation is relevant, although a quick read over that entire document would be quite helpful.

The most relevant methods from that link:

```
object.__add__(self, other)
object.__sub__(self, other)
object.__mul__(self, other)
object.__matmul__(self, other)
object.__truediv__(self, other)
object.__floordiv__(self, other)
object.__mod__(self, other)
object.__divmod__(self, other)
```

`@` can, for example, be used by implementing a `__matmul__` method:

```
class T:
    def __matmul__(self, other_t):
        pass

print(T() @ T())
```

You cannot create "custom" operators that don't already exist in the language, but you can make use of any of the hooks into existing operators.

Comment: thanks a lot, this was very useful! what about the second question, is it possible?

Comment: @Giuppox See my recent edit.